# How to find and select multiple items / values at the same time in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, find, find-and-replace, vlookup, selection

here is an over simplified example of my problem

I have 2 excel spreadsheets.

The first spreadsheet has 1 column with a list of names

John, James, Steve, Richard, Bob

The second spreadsheet also has 1 column with a list of the same names, plus some MORE names.

John, Karl, James, George, Tony, Steve, Mike, Richard, Bob, Chris

I want to find the names in the first spreadsheet, and delete them from the second spreadsheet.. so that the second spreadsheet will be left with

Karl, George, Tony , Mike, Chris

Find and Select lets me do this, but only one at a time. Is there a quicker way to search for multiple names in one go.. as I have around 1000 to check - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this would not be an automatic process, it is just a one-time thing. But I would do the following:

Add a column in Spreadsheet 2 and fill it with:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A2,[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$1000,1,FALSE)=A2,"Yes"),"No")
```

Where `A2` is the first name on the list in sheet 2, `[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1` is your spreadsheet 1; the list on spreadsheet 1 goes from 2 to 1000 (`$A$2:$A$1000`)

You will get a yes/no match that you can filter and delete:

[image: Filter by Yes/No]